# Files not getting added in docker workspace

Tags: java, maven, docker, docker-build

I have docker file

```
FROM java:8
# Install maven
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y maven


WORKDIR /code/

# Prepare by downloading dependencies
#ADD pom.xml /mmt/CouchBaseClient/CB-RestAPI/CacheService/pom.xml
#RUN ["mvn", "dependency:resolve"]
#RUN ["mvn", "verify"]
ADD cacheService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /code/cacheService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
ADD couchclient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  /code/couchclient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

EXPOSE 4567
CMD ["/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java", "-jar", "couchclient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar server cacheService.yml" ]
```

When I build this file I get the following output

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 35.46 MB
Step 1 : FROM java:8
 ---> 736600fd4ae5
Step 2 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a3466698c29d
Step 3 : RUN apt-get install -y maven
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d0fb8e77f89a
Step 4 : WORKDIR /code/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 197735d2da02
Step 5 : ADD cacheService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /code/cacheService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
 ---> 9ba30f5a2144
Removing intermediate container bd3c072ebbc6
Step 6 : ADD couchclient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /code/couchclient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
 ---> ef59315ed7fe
Removing intermediate container 0da1a69bdb51
Step 7 : EXPOSE 4567
 ---> Running in a2b32799dd6c
 ---> 3fb2b534d7c5
Removing intermediate container a2b32799dd6c
Step 8 : CMD /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar couchclient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar server cacheService.yml
 ---> Running in efb44e2bcdb3
 ---> 56637dfacc0d
Removing intermediate container efb44e2bcdb3
Successfully built 56637dfacc0d
```

But no directory named code is being made and so no files are being added even though it is giving no compilation error

Used method suggested by @VonC

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java", "-jar", "couchclient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" ]
```

and then used this command to run the image

```
docker run <image> -d <arguments>
```

Comment: I think the common practice is to put the WORKDIR directly before the ENTRYPOINT to designate the end of your operations

Comment: Try running `docker exec -it <yourContainer> bash`, then run the command `pwd` once inside.  What is the output?  According to your Dockerfile, you should be inside of `/code/` at this point.  So when you run `ls`, of course you're not going to see a directory called `/code/`, because you are already inside of that directory.  Do you have an output that verifies that you don't have the directory `/code/`?  Try running `ls /` as well, and what do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't forget that [`ADD <src>... <dest>`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) can invalidate the cache for all following instructions from the Dockerfile if the contents of `<src>` have changed. See "[Best practices](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy)" and use [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) instead of `ADD`.

In both cases (`ADD` or `COPY`), if `<dest>` doesn’t exist, it is created along with all missing directories in its path.
So no `mkdir` necessary.

```
COPY cacheService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /code/ 
COPY couchclient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  /code/
```

Otherwise, the file `cacheService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` in the *folder* `/code/cacheService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar/`!

Finally, to be *sure* that the files are where they should be, open a bash:

```
docker run --rm -it <yourImage> bash
```

Or, if you have a running container:

```
docker exec -it <yourContainer> bash
```

And check what `ls /code` returns.

Also:

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/sh <yourImage> -c "ls -alrt"
```

The [OP Legendary Hunter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2949526/legendary-hunter) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35457585/files-not-getting-added-in-docker-workspace/35458454#comment58625362_35458454) the files are there.

The issue comes from the [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) which is not fully in exec form.
Each parameter should be in its own quotes:

```
CMD ["/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java", "-jar", "couchclient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar", "server", "cacheService.yml" ]
```

If the last parameters are grouped together, `CMD` tries to access the jar file named "`couchclient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar server cacheService.yml`", which obvioulsy does not exist.
Hence the error message:

```
"Error: Unable to access jarfile couchclient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar server cacheService.yml"
```

Instead of using `CMD`, use `ENTRYPOINT` (with the sa me exec form, each arg in its own double-quotes), and leave `CMD` undefined.
That way, the arguments you will add to your `docker run` command will be passed to the `ENTRYPOINT` (which runs `java -jar ...`)

Since "server", "cacheService.yml"  are the two arguments to be passed to the running container:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java", "-jar", "couchclient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" ]
```

Build and then:

```
docker run --rm -it <image> server cacheService.yml
```

Once you know it is working, launch it in detached mode:

```
docker run -d <image> server cacheService.yml
```

Comment: You are right about `ADD` and `CMD`. Even `WORKDIR` creates the directory if it is missing.

Comment: when i run the command I see this " root@331332e5f45:/code# " without quotes and when I do ls i can see both the files i copied but I cant see the code directory physically..Where is it made? and when I try to run my image it says "Error: Unable to access jarfile couchclient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar server cacheService.yml" without quotes and " server cacheService.yml" are the program arguments I want to supply to " couchclient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ".

Comment: @Legendary_Hunter Great! The files are copied as expected. I have edited the answer to explain why you have that error message and how to avoid it.

Comment: @VonC Okay so How do I pass the arguments to my jar file because I think in CMD format we pass it in the same line...between I ran the image without arguments and it says invalid or corrupt jar file. I think its because arguments are not passed correctly.

Comment: @Legendary_Hunter I have edited the answer to provide an easy alternative: 1/ replace in your Dockerfile CMD by ENTRYPOINT. 2/ Rebuild the image. 3/ Profit!

Comment: @VonC I have edited my post to show what I tried. Please tell me if it is that what you meant or something else?

Comment: @Legendary_Hunter That looks good, but for testing I would run it in interactive tty mode first, before detaching it. `docker run --rm -it <image> <arguments>`. In your case: `docker run --rm -it <image> server cacheService.yml` (so here two arguments: `server cacheService.yml`, no double quptes needed there)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103759/discussion-between-legendary-hunter-and-vonc).

Comment: @Legendary_Hunter If you feel everything is not entirely resolved, feel free to ask a *new* question with your current errors, in order to not add too much to this already complex question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this before `WORKDIR` line:

```
RUN mkdir /code
```

Comment: Not needed.  `ADD` and `COPY` create directories for you if they do not already exist.

Comment: Yes, as explained by @VonC. My doubt was related do `WORKDIR`, but it works the same way as `ADD` and `CMD`: it creates the directory if it does not exist. Thanks anyway!